# Does unique constraint on multiple columns create index on each column

Tags: sql, postgresql

If i create a unique constraint like this `unique(colA, colB);`

Does it create 2 indexes, 1 for each column? Or how does it actually work internally?

Comment: what do you mean whit  "work internally" ?? .. anyway the each unique constraint require an  proper index  ..

Comment: Mandatory reading about indexes: https://use-the-index-luke.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will create only one index on two columns and both the column combinedly can not contain duplicate in the entire table.

You can add multiple duplicates for `colA` but considering that the `colB` is different for each row having same `colA` and vice-versa.

```
colA   colB
Tejash SO
Tejash SO1
Tejash SO2
```

Allowed

or

```
colA colB
SO1  TEJASH
SO2  TEJASH
SO3  TEJASH
```

is also allowed.

Comment: Thanks. I query colA a lot, so i have to explicitly creat another index on colA `create index on table(colA);` Is that right?

Comment: No. Of you query colA then your existing index will be used as its position in index is 1